# Why does Griffiths Example 5.5, assume the distance from wire to be $1$?

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, notation

[image]

I was under the impression the magnitude of the cross product of cursive $r$ and $dl^{'}$ would be $|\overrightarrow{r}||\overrightarrow{dl^{'}}|sin\theta$. But he simply writes it as $|\overrightarrow{dl^{'}}|sin\theta$. I looked online and found a video saying "cursive $r$ here is 1 so we get...$|\overrightarrow{dl^{'}}|sin\theta$" why is cursive $|r|$ = 1? Not to mention aren't we supposed to integrate over every little line segment, so not only should it not be 1 but should vary for each segment of our wire? As  in as we integrate along the wire, our x-component distance between $P$ and our segment of the wire ($l^{'}$) should increase as we move along the wire.

Comment: Notice that in what he is evaluating there is a hat on the cursive $r$. This hat means that you are taking the unit vector in that direction.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $\hat{r}$ denotes a unit vector. So $|\hat{r}| = 1$ by definition.

Comment: Oh my gosh this is what I was foolishly missing. Thank you for pointing that out!